# Python Flask Jinja2 css Style

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to use style sheet in flask  and apparently it does Not work properly.

I'm attaching a screen shoot to see how i have structured my  app.

my problem when I loaded my homepage I did not see the syle file applied, more I have inspected my chrome I do see only an empty style.css file .

Please have a look in that screen shoot and tell me what I did wrong , why the style is not loaded properly ?

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to `Ctrl+Shift+R` so that the browser ignores the cache when refreshing ?

Comment: Thanks gogaz, that's solve my point

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Source>> Ctrl+p

list of documents.

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have made chances to your css file and they don't seem to take effect try this, it has helped me on several occasions.

open developer toos and disable caching

for windows

> ctrl+shift+I > network > check "Disable cache" box

for Mac OS X

> Command+Option+I > network > check "Disable cache" box